# StringCch* functions and Cstring

Tags: c++, mfc, c-strings, strsafe

I am using string safe functions (StringCch*) in my code. However, some functions I want to convert the variables from `WCHAR *` to `CString`. This code is failing on the StringCchCopy functions:

```
CString sFile;
sFile.Preallocate(64);
StringCchCopy(sFile, 64, L"ini");

DWORD rv = sFile.GetAllocLength();
rv = sFile.GetLength();

TCHAR sVal[64] = {0};
StringCchCopy(sVal, 64, sFile.GetBuffer());
```

Easy answer I'm sure, but I'm a bit stumped!

And `GetAllocLength()` is returning 71. Shouldn't it return 64?

Comment: The `StringCch` functions are for working with char buffers, not string classes like `CString`. I would recommend picking one or the other instead of mixing the two.  `StringCchCopy` copies characters and does not allocate memory so I am not sure why you would expect the size of allocated memory to change

Comment: It's 71 after I Preallocate 64.

Comment: @JeffR Does this code really compile?? You should get something like this error: `HRESULT StringCchCopyW(STRSAFE_LPWSTR,std::size_t,STRSAFE_LPCWSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'CStringW' to 'STRSAFE_LPWSTR'`

Answer (score 3):

`StringCchCopy(sFile, 64, L"ini");` I'm surprised this even compiles. The first parameter of StringCchCopy is supposed to be a non-const pointer to the destination buffer. CString should not implicitly convert to such a thing (at least not as far as I'm aware from the last time I seriously used CString). So whatever this is doing, it's probably not what you want.

If you're going to do things this way, it's probably easier to use the overload of [GetBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class?view=vs-2019#getbuffer) which takes a length combined with [ReleaseBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class?view=vs-2019#releasebuffer).

`GetBuffer(X)` makes sure the CString has an internal buffer with enough space to fit X -1 characters and a null terminator, and returns a non-const pointer to that buffer.

Then `ReleaseBuffer` will cause the CString to look at whatever has been written into that buffer, find the null terminator, and figure out how long of a string it now manages. (If you want to do stuff without null terminators then go read the documentation in detail for how use it correctly for that.)

So something like

```
CString sFile;
StringCchCopy(sFile.GetBuffer(63), 64, L"ini");
sFile.ReleaseBuffer();
```

After that `sFile` should be valid and contain the data. And GetLength will reflect that.

I wouldn't worry about GetAllocLength. Though MSDN doesn't seem to explain much of anything about it, I wouldn't be surprised if it returns the entire length of an internal buffer - which CString might have decided to oversize of some particular reason. Unless you're really trying to micro-optimize something (in which case why are you even using CString), you should never need to worry about such things.

---

However there's kinda no point to all this though, since you could just do `sFile = L"ini";` That's simpler and avoids any potential off-by-one errors from making mistakes with buffer sizes.

Even if this is a simplified example, if you code has a string (pointer to a char array) then you can still just use that directly with the assignment operator of CString. (Assuming the data is null terminated and we're not getting into char vs wchar territory, in which case you may need more than StringCchCopy anyway.)

Comment: Thanks, great explanation. Trying to decide between `std::vector`, `std::string`, and `CString`. Looking for least code writing, stringcch* functionality, and automatic cleanup. Right now I've got `WCHAR *var` everywhere and it's more difficult to do cleanup and make sure I don't miss anything.

Comment: @JeffR In my experience: If your application is heavily using other ATL/MFC stuff, then `CString` is a natural choice since it'll probably work more smoothly with everything else. Otherwise, when null-terminated strings are what you're dealing with, then `std::string` is probably easiest overall (though in the case of `WCHAR` you would want `std::wstring`). In cases where you have to provide a non-const pointer to some other layer/library for it to write into the buffer, then `std::vector` can facilitate that well.